# Creating a Counter for number of times someone draw a polygon using GPS and Android

Tags: java, android, gps

I created a program in android where the user can select any title he wants using list-view which will show the next subtitle , and a button for GPS where it enables the user to find their location.

until now things run smoothly, after doing lots of research about the issue i faced, I couldn't  find the answer to begin with, I want the mobile to detect user's location, and starts from this point where the user presses on that button, the user will move in circles or polygon about 9 to 10 times, I want the mobile to tell the user that he has finished the first circle and will start with the next to count how many circles the user did ,depending on the first point.

UPDATE: 
I will provide you with example to specify what I need, lets say I am in point(xx, ll) which is the coordination I got from GPS location founder, now I will move in circle or polygon around the building and start the counter from 0, when I reach the end where I made a circle or polygon, the counter increases by 1, and keep moving like this until I reach counter number 10, how to achieve that in android?

Please I want your advice

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on what you want! You ask for advice, so what should we advice you on, how you use an int as an counter? How you get an GPS position? How you compare two GPS positions? How you detect patterns in GPS positions? Be more specific with what you want so we can help you!

Comment: Ok, I will provide you with example to specify what I need, lets say I am in point(xx, ll) which is the coordination I got from GPS location founder, now I will move in circle or polygon around the building and start the counter from 0, when I reach the end where I made a circle or polygon, the counter increases by 1, and keep moving like this until I reach counter number 10, how to achieve that in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to check if the user made a full lap and not just moved forward 50 meters then went back to the same location to count as a lap.

To check for laps no matter what is the shape you need check points in that path. The more checkpoints the better confirmation that the user followed the path. The user does not have to exactly pass through the check point he/she has to pass within 10 meters for example.

So to actually count laps you need a predefined path with checkpoints and if the user passes through all or most of the points the lap is counted.

Comment: Thank you Hussam for your answer, but I need to understand your answer more accurately:
So you suggest that I need to define path with checkpoints first. then I have to make the program check if user pass through those predefined paths / or coordination, the number of times user pass through this paths the mobile can count how many times did he pass .. is that what do you suggest?  although this seems easy theoretically but if you have code example or link to point to your answer I will be more than thankful ..

Comment: There are many examples. Here are the top google search examples that  include source code:
- https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/
- http://www.javabeat.net/location-tracker-in-android-using-gps-positioning-and-sqlite/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/665527/A-GPS-Location-Plotting-Android-Application

And this one draws the path on google maps which is something you might need:
- http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-draw-driving-route-google-map/